# Slack API keeps telling me channel_not_found when attempting to upload an image

Tags: javascript, slack-api

Like the title describes, i can't seem to figure out how to upload a local image and have it posted as a message in slack

Currently i am able to post text messages to slack without issue using the webhook url and axios post seen here:

```
const res = await axios.post(url, {
    text: 'Screenshot',
    channel: channelid

}, {
    headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
});
```

Heres the part of the script that isnt working:

```
try {

    const result = await client.files.upload({

        channels: channelid,
        initial_comment: "this is the image",

        file: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
    });

    console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

I dont understand how the channelid works in one and not the other.

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a method with an `xoxb` or `xoxp` token is different than posting a message with a webhook. When you create the webhook on the Slack Developer settings site, you are asked to choose a channel. The webhook will be able to post into that channel without your app being a channel member. When using the `xoxb` token your bot needs to be a member of the channel that's being passed in the API call. If it's not a member you can expect a `channel_not_found` or `not_in_channel` error.

Comment: Thanks for this! Seemed like i needed to specifically mention the bots name in the channel using @, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the bot to the channel using

> /invite @bot-name

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue. There was already an app in the channel, but it turns out when I `/invate @bot-name`, another user with the same name is invited to the channel. I don't know why this happens, but it just works!

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to multiple reasons,

- Slack bot is not integrated to respective channel
- Slack bot is not invited to respective channel
- You are incorrectly using **Channel Name** to upload file instead of **Channel ID**